# MS Word document shows question mark symbol � on GitHub

Tags: microsoft-word, github, hosting

I am hosting an HTML file, created using MS Word, on GitHub. For some reason, when I open the site, it shows question mark symbols in place of other symbols. [You can look at it yourself](https://gurpreetsinghmatharoo.github.io/shadows-doc/).

I have no background in anything related to this (no web programming or MS Word) so I am confused. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Thanks!

Edit: [Here's the repository](https://github.com/gurpreetsinghmatharoo/shadows-doc).

Comment: Just for confirmation, can't see it properly on a Mac either

Answer (score 1):

That symbol means that it *doesn't exist in particular text coding* (e. g. Unicode).

Change the text coding for that page in your browser.

Comment: Instead of that, how can I directly fix the html file so that it displays correctly on all browsers?